# Website error: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: iis, asp.net

The vendor one of our application has told me to call Microsoft for support on an error we are getting on their website. I'm hoping someone on here can assist. They have a feature that pulls a report and creates a PDF of users paycheck stubs. This process is not working. Below is the error we are seeing on the server.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Source Error: An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
    [ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
    System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams) +753513
    System.Drawing.ImageConverter.ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value, Type destinationType) +431
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.RawImageResourceData.FromImage(Image image) +489
    #ar.#sKg.#gIc() +252
    #ar.ResourceManager.#opk(Object sender, #Iok e) +184
    #ar.GenericCache`3.#fOe(TKey k, Boolean purging) +170
    #ar.ResourceManager.#zg(#ib resource) +118
    #ar.ResourceManager.#GHi(#ib resourceKey) +64
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Document.ResourcedCanvasItem.GetBinaryData(RawImageResourceData& data, Int32& innerKey) +65
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.#Isd(#jqc canvasItems, #orc pdfPage, PointF offset, Graphics graphics, #aqc outputContext) +4708
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.#Gsd(Page page, Graphics graphics, #aqc outputContext) +240
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.#7pk(Document document, Stream stream, String pageRange) +1619
    DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Export.Pdf.PdfExport.Export(Document document, Stream stream, String pageRange) +484
    Optimum.WebUI.Areas.ESS.Controllers.ReportController.ExportPayStub(Nullable`1 payrollID, Nullable`1 payCheckID) +8517
    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +161
    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272